# How to get an data from Hebrew Wikipedia?

Tags: php, wikipedia

I found a lot of codes to get data from en.wikipedia.org
but I dont found how to get data from Hebrew Wikiedia..
I try this:

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
$url = 'https://he.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&titles='.urlencode($query).'&format=json&utf8=';

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

$pageid = $data->query->pageids[0];
echo $data->query->pages->$pageid->title;
echo $data->query->pages->$pageid->extract;
```

and I get this errors:

```
 Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$pageids in C:\xampp\htdocs\wiki.php on line 37

 Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ in C:\xampp\htdocs\wiki.php on line 38

 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wiki.php on line 38

 Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ in C:\xampp\htdocs\wiki.php on line 39

 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wiki.php on line 39
```

Output from `var_dump($data)`

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { 
    ["batchcomplete"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["query"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { 
        ["pages"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { 
            ["899083"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (11) { 
                ["pageid"]=> int(899083) 
                ["ns"]=> int(0) 
                ["title"]=> string(8) "גוגל" 
                ["extract"]=> string(47)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Look like it is not read the code..
Help please. Thanks

Comment: After your `json_decode($json)` call, add `var_dump($data, json_last_error_msg()); die;` and post the output.

Comment: @fubar `object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["batchcomplete"]=> string(0) "" ["query"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["pages"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["899083"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (11) { ["pageid"]=> int(899083) ["ns"]=> int(0) ["title"]=> string(8) "גוגל" ["extract"]=> string(47) "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output of the `var_dump($data)`, you can access the first page like this:

```
$pages = (array) $data->query->pages;
$page = reset($pages);
```

Alternatively, you can iterate through multiple pages like this:

```
$pages = (array) $data->query->pages;

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    var_dump($page);
}
```

Once you have a single page as a variable, `$page`, you can access the properties on it as you were before.

```
echo $page->title;
echo $page->extract;
```

Comment: I got this error: `Only variables can be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\wiki.php on line 38` this is the line: `$page = reset((array) $data->query->pages);`

Comment: My bad. Updated.

Comment: Thank you so much. You genius.

Comment: sorry but I have another question. How can I get the wiki page url of the query I got his title and content?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Wikipedia API. You may be able to request the page URL in the response, but you'll have to read the documentation.

Comment: OK, Thanks again